# Two formulas one cell, if/then statement + 45 days (using dates)

Tags: date, if-statement, excel-formula

I'm not certain how to explain this but I'll do my best.  I need to have a column (I) of cells which adds 45 days to a date entered into a cell on Column B in the same row.  However, I also need the first cell (in column I) to return blank if no date is entered into the second cell (in column B).  Currently I have =B2+45.  If B2 is left blank I get the date "02/14/00" I need this to instead be left blank when no date is entered.  Apologies for any confusion.  Let me know if I should clarify anything.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This checks if B2 is blank first.  If not it does your formula if it is then it returns a blank cell.

```
=IF(B2<>"",B2+45,"")
```

Comment: @JasonT please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer, it is something only you can do.

Comment: Got It.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a good place to start. I will see what I can come up with. [conditional formatting](https://exceljet.net/formula/highlight-cells-that-contain)

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the guidance.  This link has helped with another issue I was having.